# iphone, able to hide a view and touch it?

Tags: iphone, view, touch, hidden

apparently,

```
self.hidden = YES;
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

hides the view but doesn't recognize touch events.

Is there a way of hiding a view and touching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NO way to do this. ***The solution is to make another UIView, which is empty. The only purpose of this new UIView is to catch the click.***

That is the only way to do it.

(You could also perhaps make a large transparent button, depending on your needs.)

The alpha thing is a famous gotchya. If you alpha away a UIView, it becomes unclickable. You will only be able to click it, if you can see it. Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah, tested on device, same not touchable. what do you mean by "make another view that has nothing in it." ?

Comment: Now it works! Thanks again. The empty view basically gives touch point to the original view which was not added as a subview. One minor question though, how would you pass the info from a view to another view? I'm currently letting the empty view to hand the point info to its delegate(controller) and controller uses the point info on the original view.  Connecting view to another view directly would be a bad design?

Answer (score 0):

set the backgroundColor to clear works for me. You may also need to set the text color.

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```